# geom_point not working correctly with ggMarginal

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a reprex of the issue I'm having:

```
piris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species))
ggMarginal(piris, groupFill = TRUE, groupColour = TRUE)
```

And the resulting plot is as follows:
[image: plot]

I would like to change the points within geom_point to be `pch = 21` with fill representing the `Species` (as in the plot above) but `color = "black"` so that each point has a black border. My problem is that doing so makes my marginal density plots black:

```
piris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), pch = 21, color = "black")
ggMarginal(piris, groupFill = TRUE)
```

[image]

ggMarginal seems to be looking at the border color rather than the aes(color). I removed the `groupColor` from the second plot, because setting it to `TRUE` just makes one large black density curve. I have a hunch this has something to do with `groupColor` and `groupFill` but I simply cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fills the marginal density plots with colours according groups, however, their borders are black:

```
piris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 21, colour = "black")
ggMarginal(piris, groupFill = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks @tmfmnk. I figured out by adding two separate geom_points
`geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_point()`, that I can pretty much get the same effect as pch=21 and not have the black borders on the density plots

Comment: @Ryan an even more shorter version is: `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +   geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) + geom_point()` using `colour` only once.